# Armstrong numbers in a given range using Java 8

Tags: java, stream

Was fiddling with [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8); trying to write a program for getting all [Armstrong Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) between `1` and `10_000_000`.

Following is my working solution:

```
public class ArmstrongNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntStream.range(1, 10_000_000)
                .filter((n) -> {
                    int c = 0, temp = n;
                    while (temp > 0) {
                        c += Math.pow(temp % 10, Integer.toString(n).length());
                        temp /= 10;
                    }
                    return c == n;
                }).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
153
370
371
407
1634
8208
9474
54748
92727
93084
548834
1741725
4210818
9800817
9926315
```

**Why I'm here:**

- Can this be made shorter?
- Can any other Java 8 concept be used here?
- Can the use of the `while` loop be avoided and a stream be used somehow (given that it is more elegant)?
- Review overall correctness

Here is a link to a [list of Armstrong Numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NarcissisticNumber.html) for verifying the outputs.

Please note that there is a [follow up question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/134734/104662).

Comment: Follow up question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/134734/104662

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Integer.toString(n).length()` can be assigned to its own variable.

If you wanted to stream the while loop, I suppose you could split a `toString()` version of the number via `toCharArray()` and then calculate the value for each digit individually, then summing the result via the `sum` function.

I don't know whether that'd qualify as "more elegant", though. You would get rid of `c` and `temp` as variables by doing that.

Comment: Made changes as per your suggestion. Should I share it as an update to the question?

Comment: Follow up question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/134734/104662